# Ошибка при подключении swiper js

Tags: javascript, npm, slider, swiper

При попытке начать работу с swiper js в проекте, получаю ошибку `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "swiper". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`. Код приложил

```js
import Swiper from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/css';

const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  loop: true,
})
```

```html
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: $ npm install swiper делали?

Comment: Вы случайно не swiper 7 подключает?

Comment: @Кирилл npm install swiper делал

Comment: @Greg, Вроде как 6, устанавливал с помощью name install swiper

Comment: Пробовали как указано с ./ ../или /?

Comment: @Greg--, Пробовал всё равно ошибка. Да и в документации всё устанавливается без этого

Answer (score 0):

Та же проблема, помогло только подключение с удаленного сервера

```
import Swiper from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.esm.browser.min.js";
```